# how to overlay an element in a flutter application?

Tags: flutter

I am making an audio and video player in flutter, I need to have an element at the bottom of the screen regardless of which part I navigate in my application, however I have not found the way to do it.
If someone knew how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Stack

Stack children are drawn one over other where the last is on top.

```dart
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    View(),
    Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
      child: HoverBar()
    )
  ]
)
```

#### Column

To put it below view widgets without obstructing them

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    View(),
    HoverBar()
  ]
)
```

These should work assuming you are not changing page routes, for example with a bottom navigation bar

if you are changing page routes use state management like bloc or provider to provide the `HoveBar`.

Comment: That is the problem, I need to keep this element in any part of the application where I navigate

Comment: were you planning to make it look like akin to spotify?

Comment: Exactly the same concept of Spotify

Comment: then you should be fine with using state management along with above mentioned methods